# Cannot Access Applet Containing JFileChooser From JSP

Tags: jsp, applet

I have written the following simple Applet that presents a File Uploader:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChooserDemo extends Applet implements ActionListener {
static private final String newline = "\n";
JButton openButton;
JTextArea log;
JFileChooser fc;

public void init() {


    // Create the log first, because the action listeners
    // need to refer to it.
    log = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    log.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    log.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

    // Create a file chooser
    fc = new JFileChooser();

    // Uncomment one of the following lines to try a different
    // file selection mode. The first allows just directories
    // to be selected (and, at least in the Java look and feel,
    // shown). The second allows both files and directories
    // to be selected. If you leave these lines commented out,
    // then the default mode (FILES_ONLY) will be used.
    //
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    // fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    // Create the open button. We use the image from the JLF
    // Graphics Repository (but we extracted it from the jar).
    openButton = new JButton("Open a File...");
    openButton.addActionListener(this);



    // For layout purposes, put the buttons in a separate panel
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); // use FlowLayout
    buttonPanel.add(openButton);


    // Add the buttons and the log to this panel.
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            // This is where a real application would open the file.
            log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
        } else {
            log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
        log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

        // Handle save button action.
    } 
}




}
```

It runs fine except when I try to include it within a Web Application.  I compiled it into a JAR and signed the JAR.  Below is the JSP File referencing the Applet:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome JSP-Applet Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="FileChooserDemo" codebase="./applet" archive="Applet.jar" 
  width="400" height="400">
  <jsp:fallback>
   <p>Unable to load applet</p>
   </jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to open from my browser.  I get the following error from the Java console Window:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Users\jatoui\Documents read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.exists(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.createShellFolder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.getPersonal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getDefaultDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.blackducksoftware.proserv.applets.FileChooserDemo.init(FileChooserDemo.java:26)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Users\jatoui\Documents read)
```

Is there any way to overcome this???

Comment: You can refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850351/applet-and-jsp-communication/27358112#27358112 Good Luck..........

Answer (score 1):

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    (java.io.FilePermission C:\Users\jatoui\Documents read)
```

An applet needs to be digitally signed by the developer, and trusted by the end user, before it can read or write files on the end-user's machine.  (Unless it is deployed in a plug-in 2 JRE and used the JNLP API Services for accessing the local file system.

Comment: In case you missed the memo in my original posting: "I compiled it into a JAR and signed the JAR."

Comment: Are you being prompted to trust the code?  Is the code called by JavaScript?

Comment: This prompt is not appearing and the code is referenced within the JSP through the <JSP:PLUGIN> tag

Comment: *"prompt is not appearing"*  It should appear.  What is the output of `jarsigner -verify Applet.jar`?

Comment: I get the following output: "jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months."

Comment: That warning message is not the problem.  Can a *standard* (e.g. no security manager) app. read the file(s) in `C:\Users\jatoui\Documents`?

Comment: If I run the applet directly from Eclipse as an applet, it works fine