# Embedded applet in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I have embedded applet in jsp with applet tag and this not the way to integrate applet in jsp ,So I replaced my applet tag with jsp:plugin but I dont get any image in applet.Below is the code snippet

```
<applet     name="viewerApplet"     id="TViewerApplet"     width="100%"     height="500"     code="com.applet.TViewerApplet.class"     align="baseline"     codebase="."     mayscript="mayscript"     archive="SignedViewer.jar,cmbview81.jar"> </applet>
```

replaced with following code

```
 <jsp:plugin code="com.applet.TViewerApplet.class" codebase="." type="applet" name="viewerApplet"     width="100%"     height="500" archive="SignedViewer.jar,cmbview81.jar"> 
    </jsp:plugin>
```

What is wrong .Please guide.
Edit:
With applet tag its working fine.

Comment: You can refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850351/applet-and-jsp-communication/27358112#27358112 Good Luck..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing terms.

JSP is server technology, it renders an HTML page.

Applet is client technology, it works inside the HTML page (possibly rendered by a JSP).

So, when the Applet starts running the JSP has finished a long time ago. Use the applet tag as you would do, because to the browser it won't matter at all that the page was generated by a JSP or not.

Answer (score 0):

Place your applet jars in the folder where your jsp's are palced.

ex.

Beside the WEB-INF folder (includes yoru jsp's and your applet jars).